# HttpListener Remote IP Address (client)

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

So I am using HttpListener (webSocket) to listen for a connection.  A connection is received and fires the event to deal with the context:

```
    private void WebSocketServer_OnWebSocketContext(object sender, System.Net.WebSockets.HttpListenerWebSocketContext context)
    {
        OnWebSocketContext(context);
    }

        private async void     OnWebSocketContext(System.Net.WebSockets.HttpListenerWebSocketContext context)
    {
     ...
     }
```

My question is, how do I get the connecting machine's IP address.   This is all done via a browser (obviously http).   I cannot figure where the IP address of the connecting machine is found in the context (or is it)??

Answer (score 4):

string ipAddress = httpListenerContext.Request.RemoteEndPoint.Address.ToString();

Comment: Thanks, Jay.   I thought I had checked that and it didn't have a Remote_Addr key but I could have missed it.  I'll give it a shot tonight.  Thanks!

Comment: Well neither of those headers exist.  Here are the Header keys I have: Origin,Sec-WebSocket-Version,Sec-WebSocket-Key,Sec-WebSocket-Extensions,Cache-Control,Connection,Pragma,Upgrade,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Host,User-Agent.  Still trying to find the IP somewhere.  Any more ideas?

Comment: sorry for the confusing, I edit the answer, hope it will work this time

Comment: Thanks Jay, Looking forward to it.